# Unittest SOQL query

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I Have the following class and unit test but I cant seem to get coverage for my class, what am I missing thanks in advance

```
public with sharing class quoteList {

    public List<Opportunity> myOpp {get;set;}
    public String currentRecordId {get;set;}

    public quoteList(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

   currentRecordId  = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');
   myOpp = [SELECT (SELECT Name FROM Quotes ORDER by Name), Name,StageName, CloseDate , Amount FROM Opportunity WHERE Account.Id=:currentRecordId ORDER by Name];

    } 
    public List<Opportunity> getOpp() {  
       return myOpp;
      }      
}
```

Test class:

```
@isTest
public class quoteListTestClass {

static testMethod void testquoteList() { 

    string currentRecordId ='0010E000005LqsI';
     //create an account 
        Account acct = new Account(Name='TEST_ACCT');
        insert acct;

        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(Name='test',StageName='Closed Won',CloseDate=system.today()+1, AccountId = acct.id);
        insert opp;

    Quote Quot = new Quote(Name='TEST_Quot',OpportunityId=opp.id);
        insert Quot;

    List<Opportunity>  myOpp=[SELECT (SELECT Name FROM Quotes ORDER by Name), Name,StageName, CloseDate , Amount FROM Opportunity WHERE Account.Id=:acct.id ORDER by Name];
    system.debug(opp);
    system.debug(myOpp);
    system.debug(myOpp.size());
    System.assertEquals(1, myOpp.size()); 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow this approach for testing the controller from your test method. Currently you have not created any instance of controller class which could fire the constructor.

In the below code, it has been assumed you are using an extension of Account standardcontroller.

```
//create account and related records
Account acct = new Account(Name='testAccount');  
insert acct;
Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(Name='test',StageName='Closed Won',CloseDate=system.today()+1, AccountId = acct.id);
insert opp;

Quote Quot = new Quote(Name='TEST_Quot',OpportunityId=opp.id);
insert Quot;

//create pageReference
PageReference page = Page.MyVFP;
Test.setCurrentPage(page);

//pass parameter to the page
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',acct.Id);

//create an instance of controller.
ApexPages.StandardController standrdcontroller = new ApexPages.StandardController(acct);
quoteList myController = new quoteList(standrdcontroller);
System.assertEquals(.....);

//retrieve opportunity list
List<Opportunity> lstOppty = myController.getOpp();
System.assertEquals(.....); //do assert for opportunity.
```

Comment: Thanks! for your help. I do an Assert on opp. which still only gives me a coverage of 71% where the last 2 lines are not covered my assert is as follows : `System.assertEquals(1, myController.myOpp.size());`

Comment: check if this works System.assertEquals(1, lstOppty.size());